# Find the columns which are identical in all rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get the column names which have identical values in all rows.

For example in this dataframe I want the output to be "Name"

```
Name    Age City
0   Riti    34  Sydeny
1   Riti    30  Delhi
2   Riti    16  New York
3   Riti    30  Delhi
4   Riti    30  Delhi
5   Riti    30  Mumbai
6   Riti    40  Delhi
7   Riti    30  Delhi
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Check with `nunique`

```
df.columns[df.nunique()==1]
Index(['Name'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: you could add more explanation to your answer , will be helpful to understand it.